# change JAVA_HOME to match your environment JAVA_HOME="/opt/java"

Tags: java, linux

I'm trying to edit my env.sh file to add java path in linux:

As needed, uncomment the following line and
   change JAVA_HOME to match your environment

```
JAVA_HOME="/opt/java"
```

I did this  JAVA_HOME=/sys/java/jdk1.6.0_20 
     export JAVA_HOME

when i do runcat.sh it gives me an error saying JAVA_HOME IS NOT SET CORRECTLY.
ANYONE PLEASE HELP ME...
sorry for my english

Comment: i don't get the problem

Comment: What gives the error?

Comment: # *********************************************************
# ***    As needed, uncomment the following line and    ***
# ***    change JAVA_HOME to match your environment     ***
# *********************************************************
# JAVA_HOME="/opt/java"
above is what mentioned in env.sh file so what would i add as JAVA_HOME my java is here /sys/java/jdk1.6.0_20

Comment: Please edit your question, not comment!

Comment: when i do runcat.sh it gives me an error saying JAVA_HOME IS NOT SET CORRECTLY.

Comment: Are you talking about Tomcat?

Comment: Most likely you are not sourcing the script. You should type source env.sh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [JEnv](http://www.jenv.be/) for doing this.

http://www.jenv.be/

> jEnv is a command line tool to help you forget how to set the
>   JAVA_HOME environment variable

Answer (score 0):

You're not executing that java executable at the path you've specified then.

execute >which java. You may find a surprise.

Just to be sure execute ./java at the bin folder of the java version you added to your JAVA_HOME and see if you get the same error.

And finally, I hope your PATH is well set to add the java bin executable you want to run.

I'm sure you're having a problem with different versions. Give it a try.

Comment: No reasons to give me a negative...